# dynamic content load in sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to do a dynamic content load into sharepoint using a links and a div, but I can't seem to get it to work.
So this is the code in my .txt file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("bios");
$('a .name').click(function bios() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#contactInfo').load(url);
    return false;
});
</script>

<h3>Meet the Team</h3>
<ul>
<li> <a class="name" href="htmlContent/emp1.htm">employee1</a></li>
<li> <a class="name" href="htmlContent/emp2.htm">employee2</a></li>
<li> <a class="name" href="htmlContent/emp3.htm">employee3</a></li>
<li> <a class="name" href="htmlContent/emp4.htm">employee4</a></li>
<li> <a class="name" href="htmlContent/emp5.htm">employee5</a></li>
</ul>
</br>
<div id="contactInfo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this small tweak to make jQuery work nicely with sharepoint:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("bios");

function bios() {
    jQuery('a .name').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); /*<----this will prevent the default click action*/
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#contactInfo').load(url);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Still didn't work. It tries to function like a normal link and leave the page instead of load the content in the div. Do appreciate the way you cleaned up the code though. That would definitely make the push more effective.

Comment: That is how the anchor tag functions...if you want to ignore the default, try the above edit.

Comment: I took your code verbatim and pasted in lieu of my own. Still didn't work. Perhaps I need to add a ".preventDefault();"?

Comment: That is in my edit above. Add the `e` to the click handler as a parameter and add the line `e.preventDefault();` before the rest of the code in the handler.

Comment: ahh, the edit hadn't loaded before your comment. LOL thanks!

Comment: Nope, still leaves the page.

Comment: OK, try changing `e.preventDefault();` to `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` This may be something that is quirky with sharepoint, those should stop the navigation of the link when clicked.

Comment: Still didn't work. It's like the Script isn't firing at all and is just being bypassed.